# Tie R script and QlikSense software together

Tags: r, qlikview, qliksense

I require `qliksense` to create an Excel file when the user selects a set of tuples and `R` to automatically pick up this file, perform my script on the file. My script then creates another CSV file which I then want qliksense to automatically pick up and perform some predefined operations on it. Is there any way I can link the two of these software together in such a manner?

So to clarify the flowchart is: Qlik gets a large data set -> the user selects a set of rows and creates csv -> My custom R script (picks up this csv automatically) is run on the csv and creates a new csv -> qlik picks it up (automatically) and visually displays the results of the program

Is there any kind of wrapper software to tie them together? Or is it a better idea to perhaps just make some sort of UI that works with R in the background and the user can manually pass the file through the UI? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know about R part but there is no straight approach in Sense. You probably need to build some NodeJS or C# app that monitor specific folder for file changes and then reload the Sense app using the Sense API

Answer (score 1):

Check out the R extension that has been developed on http://branch.Qlik.com , extensions are being created and added all the time. You will probably need to create an account to access the project but once you have the direct link is below.

http://branch.qlik.com/#/project/5677d32d7f70718900987bdd